# Permitir interatividade no UIScroolView e impedir interação com o conteúdo dentro dele enquanto rola

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Existe algum meio de impedir a interação do usuário com o conteúdo dentro de um UIScrollView?

Tenho um ScrollView the contém UIViews dentro dele.

Nessas UIviews contém apenas um objeto, UIImage.

```
UIScroolView
 ||
\  /
 \/
----------------------------------------------------------------
          ______    ______
         |      |  |      |
         |      |  |      |   <-- UIview com imagem dentro
         |______|  |______|

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Quero permitir que o usuário interaja com o UIScrollView, para poder rolar de um lado para o outro, porém, enquanto está rolando, não pode interagir com os objetos de dentro (as imagens). As imagens possuem um evento de drag'n drop atachado.

O efeito de tocar e arrastar só pode iniciar se o scroll estiver parado.

Até aqui, funciona como o esperado, porém, a interatividade com o scroll fica desativada para que isso aconteça pois desconheço um meio de desativar somente o conteúdo de dentro do UIScrollView.

Estou aplicando `userInteractionEnabled` e isso desativa a interação por completo enquanto está rolando. Quando termina de rolar, `userInteractionEnabled` é setado como `YES`.

```
- (void)scrollInteractionEnabled:(bool)val :(UIScrollView *)sender
{

    /*
    O objeto UIScrollView está setado como objeto.delegate = self
    */

    //  Esse está e uso e funciona bem.
    // O problema é que fica desativado por completo, não permitindo rolar
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = val;

    /*
    Algumas combinações que tentei, sem sucesso
    */
    //sender.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;         //sender.scrollEnabled = YES;
    //sender.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
}


/*
Os métodos abaixo capturam eventos de rolagem, especificamente quando desacelera e quando para.
Isso é necessário para reverter o valor de userInteractionEnabled
*/
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{
    [self scrollInteractionEnabled:NO:sender];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    //[super scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView willDecelerate:decelerate];
    if(!decelerate) {
        [self scrollInteractionEnabled:YES:scrollView];
    }
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self scrollInteractionEnabled:YES:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self scrollInteractionEnabled:YES:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self scrollInteractionEnabled:YES:scrollView];
}
```

Algo que parece mais próximo de resolver é `[objeto_scroll setCanCancelContentTouches:YES]`. Obviamente testei e não funcionou.

Também considero uso de alguma biblioteca, classe, ou o que for funcional.
O motivo de tudo isso é a classe que utilizo tem um bug que quando toca num objeto dentro do scroll enquanto está rolando, o efeito de drag não é detectado. Somente o evento de touch é executado.

[edit]

Resolvido conforme dica do @MárioKlein

```
- (void)scrollInteractionEnabled:(bool)val :(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    /*
    Possuo 2 objetos do tipo UIScrollView, por isso foi necessário identifica o Scroll em contexto (onde contém os objetos)
    */
    if (sender == mScrollView) {

        // Itera os objetos de dentro, habilitando e desabilitando a interatividade de cada um individualmente ao invés de aplicar ao UIScrollView.  
        for (UIView* subview in mScrollView.subviews)
        {
            subview.userInteractionEnabled = val;
        }

    } else if (!mScrollView.isDragging || !mScrollView.isDecelerating) {
        // Se o scroll parar de se mover, é habilitada a interatividade nele mesmo. Essa regra ainda continua.
        mScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        mScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel,

Tente navegar pela árvore de views `[scrollView subviews]` e defina todos eles com `userInteractionEnabled = false` enquanto está realizando o scroll. Quando terminar, faça o inverso (`userInteractionEnabled = true`).